# Jenkins with SonarQube plugin

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Im running Jenkins and SonarQube in docker. I’ve added the plug-in with auto install. Created the token for jenkins, created the sonarqube tool with sonarqube as the name of the tool, and created the jenkinsfile in the main repo of gitea. But I keep getting the error below. I installed all the containers and configured this morning. I’ve run this before to give it a whirl and did not have issues then. But that was a year ago. Any idea is welcome.

The jenkinsfile used:

```
node { 
   stage('SCM') { 
     checkout scm 
   } 
   
   stage('SonarQube Analysis') { 
      def scannerHome = tool 'sonar-scanner'; 
      withSonarQubeEnv() { 
        sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner" 
      } 
   } 
}
```

And the error:

```
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonarqube/bin/sonarqube: not found
```

Installed and configured as per documentation from Jenkins and SonarQube and still not finding the tool to scan.

Comment: Can you add the jenkinsfile which is producing the error?

Comment: Please see below sorry in my phone. node {
  stage('SCM') {
    checkout scm
  }
  stage('SonarQube Analysis') {
    def scannerHome = tool 'sonar-scanner';
    withSonarQubeEnv() {
      sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner"
    }
  }
}

Comment: I don't know all the details, but you can review the configuration steps and the pipeline I purpose on my response :).

Answer (score 0):

I configure the follow installation on jenkins manager tools ( https://<YOUR_JENKINS>/manage/configureTools)

[image]

And the credentials and a url for my sonar server in jenkins manager configuration (https://<YOUR_JENKINS>/manage/configure)

[image]

And using this jenkinsfile, the scan succeed without a problem. It's important to note that the `tool` name and the name used in `withSonarQubeEnv` must match the configured in jenkins manager.

```
pipeline {

    stages {
        stage('SonarQube Analysis') { 
            steps {
                script {
                    withSonarQubeEnv('Sonarqube') {
                        sh "${tool('sonar-scanner')}/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=myProjectKey -Dsonar.projectName=myProjectName"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```